# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.ts(2347) --- mongodb

Tags: typescript, mongodb

I use typescript and mongodb driver of mongodb database, when I create a collection, the type warn occur:

Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.

type warn code:

```
import clientPromise from '../../../lib/mongodb';

const database = clientPromise.db(process.env.DATABASE_NAME);
const posts = database.collection<Post>('posts');
```

../../../lib/mongodb file code: mongodb version: "^4.10.0",

```
// This approach is taken from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;

let client;
let clientPromise;

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local');
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri);
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
    // global._mongoClientPromise = client;
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
  // clientPromise = client;
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;
```

[image]